# Angular retrieve/set the value of a div's innerHTML as value in another div

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am using Angular and am trying to use/set the innerHTML as text of a div as the value of another div. The code is somewhat like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div #instr class="instructions" innerHTML="{{ 'somtext' | translate }}"></div>              
    </div>
    <div class="xxx">
        <clipboard [value]="instructions.innerHTML"></clipboard>          
    </div>                                 
</div>
```

The problem is if I use instructions.innerHTML, it prints all the html tags etc. I want the value to contain the text as it appears in the first div, and not the tags

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to render with the same styles and structure as it appears in your div then you need to display it with a `[innerHTML]="value"` inside your clipboard component, there is no way to do this from outside the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text content of the div with `innerText`, as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndvecs):

```
<clipboard [value]="instr.innerText"></clipboard>
```

Comment: innerText is lot better. However, I have an issue. I also have some <ol><li></li></ol> numbered list in my text and I do not want to lose the numbers. Is there a way to retain the numbers in the text

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you incorrectly refer to a variable. What is the *instruction* in:

```
<clipboard [value]="instructions.innerHTML"></clipboard>
```

Perhaps you need to write in *instr*:

```
<clipboard [value]="instr.innerHTML"></clipboard>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YOCm4koIDf9TeZMy7Wp6?p=preview